# Which themes are available in PresentationFramework.Aero2?

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml, themes

My WPF application is too bright, I want to apply a dark theme to it.

On my computer, Explorer is using a dark theme. Can I use the same theme as Explorer on my WPF application? And if so, how do I do that?

I've seen examples saying that I can add this to my `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And this works, my theme is now changed. **But what are the other, available themes? And what d they look like?**

And I guess since "Aero2" is a thing, this probably looks more modern. I tried changing the `Source` property to `/PresentationFramework.Aero2;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml` (notice the "2") but it threw an error:

```
IOException: Cannot locate resource 'themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml'.
```

Comment: Aero2 is old and i don't think you'll like what you find there. I suggest you take a look at https://mahapps.com/docs/themes/usage

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I really wish they would put up some screenshots of the themes. Takes a while to try them all to see what they look like. And (more specifically on-topic) I am still curious to how someone can resonate that the `Source` should be set to `/PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Switch WPF Built-In Themes

For .NET Core 3.1 you have to merge the theme dictionary into the application resources.

```
<Application x:Class="YourApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFThemes"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

For .NET Framework, you have to merge the theme resource dictionary, too, but additionally you have to reference the corresponding theme assembly in your project. In  your project, right click *References*, select *Add Reference...* and expand the *Assemblies* tree item. Search for *PresentationFramework*, then check the check box for the theme assembly you want to reference and click *OK*.

[image: Reference Manager - Assemblies view with PresentationFramework.Aero2 theme assembly checked.]

### Built-In Themes

- AeroLite - Windows 8 to 10 similar theme

  ```
  /PresentationFramework.AeroLite;component/themes/AeroLite.NormalColor.xaml
  ```
- Aero2 - Windows 8 to 10 similar theme

  ```
  /PresentationFramework.Aero2;component/themes/Aero2.NormalColor.xaml
  ```
- Aero - Windows 7 theme

  ```
  /PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml
  ```
- Luna - Windows XP theme

  - Green variant

    ```
    /PresentationFramework.Luna;component/themes/Luna.NormalColor.xaml
    ```
  - Silver variant

    ```
    /PresentationFramework.Luna;component/themes/Luna.Metallic.xaml
    ```
  - Olive variant

    ```
    /PresentationFramework.Luna;component/themes/Luna.Homestead.xaml
    ```
- Royale - Windows XP Media Center theme

  ```
  /PresentationFramework.Royale;component/themes/Royale.NormalColor.xaml
  ```
- Classic - Windows 95/98/2000 similar theme

  ```
  /PresentationFramework.Classic;component/themes/Classic.xaml
  ```

### Other Themes

> On my computer, Explorer is using a dark theme. Can I use the same theme as Explorer on my WPF application? And if so, how do I do that?

No, you cannot. There is no built-in theme for light and dark mode. The most suitable theme for your application will be picked under the current operating system if you did not specify or override this behavior otherwise. For me on Windows 10 that is *Aero2*.

If you want to have a more modern theme with light and dark mode support, you have to look at thrid party libraries like [MahApps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) or [MaterialDesignInXAML](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit). Those also provided automatic theme switching based on the operating system light or dark setting.

Comment: If you need images to see what the themes look like, you have to be more specific which control, e.g. a `Button` in which state. Since there are many controls it is most likely better to prepare a solution yourself and try out all themes interactively.